# Downgrade jquery from 1.5.2 to 1.4.2

Tags: 7, javascript

How can I downgrade the jQuery library on Drupal 7 from 1.5.2 to 1.4.2; it looks like i've lost some functionality in Panels and Views after enabling the jQuery Update module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jQuery Update module updates Drupal's jQuery library from 1.4.4 to 1.5.2. If you don't *want* version 1.5.2 then you just need to uninstall the jQuery Update module and everything will go back to normal.

If you want to use jQuery Update *just* to update the jQuery UI library to v1.8.11 it looks like you'll have to patch the jquery_update.module file directly, as the version numbers for the base library are hardcoded into the [`jquery_update_jquery_replace()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21jquery_update%21jquery_update.module/function/jquery_update_jquery_replace/7) function using this code:

```
switch ($version) {
  case '1.5':
    $trueversion = '1.5.2';
    break;
  case '1.7':
    $trueversion = '1.7.1';
    break;
}
```